# encrypted payload in tcpdump or pcap

Tags: pcap, libpcap, tcpdump

Is it possible if I have a tcpdump set up at the gateway of the company LAN, such that all incoming and outgoing traffic is captured, that someone can decrypt the encrypted payload of https packets ? if so, what tools are used to decrypt the payloads of the packets ?

Thanks

-SF

Comment: Maybe this is a question for ServerFault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is not possible unless you have the NSA or the keys at your disposal. But if you do (have the keys), Wireshark can help,

> The SSL dissector is fully functional and even supports advanced features such as
>   decryption of SSL if the encryption key can be
>   provided and Wireshark is compiled against GnuTLS (rather than OpenSSL
>   or bsafe). This works for RSA private keys.
>
> http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL